# How to implement Master-Detail component in the community edition of the ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid-angular

I want to implement ag-grid Master Detail feature.However it is an enterprise level feature and i am currently using community version and due to some constraints my organization does not want to purchase the license .Is there any other way to achieve this?Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this options to your colDef:

```
gridOptions= {
   fullWidthCellRendererFramework: RowDetailsRendererComponent,
   isFullWidthCell: (rowNode: RowNode) => rowNode.flower,
   doesDataFlower: (data: any) => true,
   embedFullWidthRows: true
}
```

Where RowDetailsRendererComponent have to implements AgRendererComponent class

and have to contain child ag-grid for example

```
@Component({
  template: '<ag-grid ...></ag-grid>' // child grid
})
export class RowDetailsRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  agInit(params): void {}
  refresh(params: any): boolean {}
}
```

Comment: Anything more recent? I can't to get Master-Detail work with the community edition :\

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/full-width-rows/  - here is the reference to this solution

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to replace a row by the content of a component. A solution for the initial problem could be in my opinion use this code with a "frameworkComponent" to implement the expand/collapse button. You can check how to use add a button to a ag-Grid here: 
[Example to add a botton to a cell in ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-angular-components)